# Angular velocity of a L-shaped rod about a pivot

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-velocity

Suppose I have a *L-shaped* rod ABC such that it is pivoted at *B*(the point where 2 rods **AB** and **BC** are joined, thus forming the *L*). Now, if I pull the end *C* with a constant velocity, the system acquires an angular velocity about the pivoted point(or *the hinge*). I'm having a problem in calculating this angular velocity. Is it due to both of the rods(joined together), or due to the **rod only** which is pulled with a constant velocity? How do I see it? Can someone help me in analysing the situation?

Comment: are the length and mass of both rods equal ?

Comment: Yup, it's an ideal L-shape.

Comment: @AbhinavTahlani I gave an answer but just realized that problem has something missing is the L shaped material is initially at rest

Comment: Yes, it's at rest initially.

Comment: And also what you mean by constant velocity, if you pull the system with continuously at one direction or an initial kick

Comment: @Butane I think he is talking about the angular velocity at steady state, when net torque on system is $0$

Comment: @maverick but if L shape is rigid then every point on the shape have to rotate with the same angular velocity

Comment: @ Butane yes, you are correct at this point  , I would not disagree with that

Comment: Where you got stuck?

Comment: Please provide more details on the question

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. I've got my answer...the angular velocity indeed is v/BC. It's true that for a rigid shape, we can consider the angular velocity for evey point on it to be the same( two points on the same shape just can't rotate differently, unless it is stretchable or extensible like that). I was confused a bit about the rod AB, if it would have any impact on the angular velocity. What resolved my doubt was when I thought of the situation like two rods having different pivots (and the pivots superimposed on one another!). As for the velocity, it was only an initial kick.